# Time-Varying Copulas (GAUSS)

Tags: correlation, copula, kalman

Could anyone suggest me how to begin with Time-varying Copulas or Stochastic Copulas? I'm looking for the GAUSS code, however it seems there are only MATLAB code available over the internet.

I'm trying to apply it to Time-varying correlation via state-space representation and Kalman filter.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried R?
http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/tools-in-r-for-estimating-time-varying-copulas

Comment: Just port it yourself, Paton's code is not difficult.