# Gaussian Time-varing copula in R

Tags: r, copula

I want to estimate the parameters of time-varing Normal Copula using R. A bivariate Normal copula is defined as following:

[image]

The dynamic equation of dependance parameter ρ is :
[image]

So I need the identify the parameters ω,α and β. 
To be more specific, I wander if there is Patton's code in R which allows the dependence parameter ρ to vary over time.

Comment: What is the model for the above formulas? Do you have a refernence? What is $\Lambda$? Please provide more details.

Comment: see here: http://quant.stackexchange.com/a/7022/12

Comment: this is my reference [Filho et al (2013)](http://www.tandfonline.com.sci-hub.club/doi/abs/10.1080/14697688.2012.739726#.VhfDYOztmko) CDVine R package does not provide time-varing Copula code.

Comment: So you're saying that the packages mentioned in the linked answer are not sufficient?

Comment: Also, @Nourhaine, you seem to have two profiles, please ask them to be [merged](http://quant.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is no but the question in this form seems interesting enough.

Comment: Patton's code for time varying normal copula is available in MATLAB.